# Fetch data from a 2 many to many table

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am using codeigniter activerecord and I am fetching information of 2 many to many table but undefined index is appearing in my error log in the CI view

```
 public function editCommission($data){
    $this->db->select('client_user_cashin.id, client.account_name, property.property_name, client.unit_number, client.reservation_date, users.givenname, users.surname, client_user.sl_rate, sl_position.position, cash_in.cash_recieved, comm_status.comm_status, computation_type.com_type');
    $this->db->from('client_user_cashin');
    $this->db->join('client_user', 'client_user.id = client_user_cashin.client_user_id');
    $this->db->join('client', 'client.id = client_user.client_id');
    $this->db->join('property_commision', 'property_commision.id = client.property_commision_id');
    $this->db->join('property', 'property.id = client.property_id');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = client_user.user_id');
    $this->db->join('sl_position', 'sl_position.id = client_user.sl_position_id');  
    $this->db->join('cash_in', 'cash_in.id = client_user_cashin.cash_in_id');
    $this->db->join('comm_status', 'comm_status.id = client_user_cashin.comm_status_id');
    $this->db->join('computation_type', 'computation_type.id = cash_in.comp_type_id');     
    $this->db->order_by('client_user_cashin.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Fetch the data in the edit form

Comment: Put here error message for more reference. Because we do not know what are the column name in your Database table.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply left-join on all the joins like

```
$this->db->join('client_user', 'client_user.id = client_user_cashin.client_user_id','left');
```